# When can the Keeper use Trauma cards?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I understand I need to pick up a Mythos card during the Keeper's turn, but when do I pick up and use Trauma cards?

Answer (score 4):

The rules on Trauma cards are on pg25 of the **Rules of Play** book.

> These cards can *only* be played by the keeper *immediately after an investigator takes damage or horror*.  The only exception to this restriction is if an investigator has zero sanity, in which case the keeper may play one insanity Trauma card on the investigator as a keeper action (once per turn per insane investigator).

The main way to get Trauma cards is to use Keeper actions, particularly the **Evil Presence** and **Dark Ritual** actions.  (All 5 stories in the base game have one or the other available to the Keeper)